# Rustにおけるオブジェクトのインスタンスを指すナントカの呼び名は？

Tags: rust

以下のRustのコードにて、s1は一般的に何と呼ばれますか？
Javaなどでは"参照"と呼ばれると思います。

```
fn main() {
   let s1 = String::from("hello, world");
   println!("msg: {}", s1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rustの公式ガイド（英語版）で使われている用語に基づいて回答しますね。

> 以下のRustのコードにて、s1は一般的に何と呼ばれますか？

このあたりの文章ですと、
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#storing-values-with-variables

`String::from("hello, world")`は

- `String`の値、`String`値　（a String value）
- `String`のインスタンス　（an instance of String）

`s1`は

- 変数　（a variable）
- `String`のインスタンスに束縛された変数　（a variable bound to an instance of String）
- （変数という言葉を省略して）`String`の値

のように呼ばれています。

私個人の感覚ですと、Rustでインスタンスと呼ぶことは少なくて、値と呼ぶことが圧倒的に多い印象です。

> Javaなどでは"参照"と呼ばれると思います。

Javaではオブジェクトには暗黙的な参照（ポインター）を通してアクセスし、プリミティブ型の値は直接持ちます。ですから、質問のコードでは「参照」と呼んで問題ありません。しかし、Rustには「暗黙的」な参照はなく、デフォルトは値持ちになります。もし、参照が必要なときは以下のように明示的に作ります。

```rust
let s1 = String::from("hello, world");
let r1 = &s1;  // 不変参照を作る

let mut s2 = String::from("hello, world");
let r2 = &mut s2;  // 可変参照を作る
```

上の例ですと、`&s1`は

- `s1`の不変参照　（an immutable reference to `s1`）
- `String`の値を指す不変参照　（an immutable reference to a `String` value）

`&mut s2`は

- `s2`の可変参照　（a mutable reference to `s2`）
- `String`の値を指す可変参照　（a mutable reference to a `String` value）

`r1`と`r2`は厳密には「〜〜の不変参照／可変参照に束縛された変数」と呼ぶのが正しいでしょうが、いちいち変数と言わずに、単に「〜〜の不変参照／可変参照」と呼んでもいいと思います。